# how to delete all directory oracle database

Tags: database, oracle, server

I want to ask, how to delete all folder in Oracle database I have stopped all of the services but if I wanted to delete the folder it won't work because it opened by another application?[all services was stopped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACadd.png)

[still cant delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcgL1.png)

Comment: Why is it a secret to show use the filename which you cannot delete? Also, please don't paste pictures, describe the problem in text.

Comment: Pop over to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-utilities and you can use those tools to show what process has a file open.